# Javascript/PHP - Reordering JSON array randomly causes null value and deletes everything

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, null

I have a random issue while trying to reorder items in a JSON array via JS/PHP, this occurs when the array has more than 1000 items.

Example of my `Users.json` file:

```
[
    {
        "ID_id": "123abc",
        "ST_username": "johndoe",
        "ST_email": "j@example.com",
        "ST_fullname": "John Doe",
    },
{
        "ID_id": "def345",
        "ST_username": "sarahdoe",
        "ST_email": "s@example.com",
        "ST_fullname": "Sarah Doe",
    },
{
        "ID_id": "fgh567g",
        "ST_username": "markdoe",
        "ST_email": "mark@example.com",
        "ST_fullname": "Mark Doe",
    }

    // + additional 1000 similar items in this array
]
```

So, first of all, I get the JSON file's data and decode it into a PHP array:

```
$tableName = $_GET['tableName'];  // Lets' say $tableName is 'Users'

// fetch data from 'Users.json'
$data = file_get_contents($tableName. '.json');
$data_array = json_decode($data, true);
```

Then I call this function in JS:

```
function reorderTableData() {
    var newOrderArray = [];
    var data_arrayStr = JSON.stringify(<?php echo json_encode($data_array) ?>);
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(data_arrayStr);
    var reorderedData = JSON.stringify(jsonData, newOrderArray);
    
    $.ajax({
     url : "reorder-table-data.php",
     type: 'POST',
     data: 'tableName='+'<?php echo $tableName ?>'+'&reorderedData='+encodeURIComponent(reorderedData),
       success: function(data) {
       location.reload();
    
        // error
        }, error: function(e) {  
    }});
    }
}
```

My `reorder-table-data.php` code:

```
$tableName = $_POST['tableName'];
$reorderedData = $_POST['reorderedData'];

$data_array = json_decode($reorderedData, true);

// Encode back to JSON
$data = json_encode(array_values($data_array), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
file_put_contents($tableName. '.json', $data);

// echo JSON object
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Sometimes this code erases everything and all you see is `null` in the `Users.json` file, all data got lost.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're re-stringifying and re-parsing the data multiple times in PHP and in JS. `json_encode` returns a valid JSON string, you should not re-encode it in PHP, and you should not stringify it in JS.

Comment: Not related to the question, but it looks like the code leaks sensitive information if that json file is public, and even if it wasn't, the entire data is readable at a client. Also, it's dangerous to use a filename, which can be compromized by a client.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a suggestion about how to avoid those multiple parsings and still get the result done?

Comment: Actually I've no clue what is the desired result. Stringifying and parsing the same object/JSON back and forth doesn't have any effect on the value.

Comment: I am stringifying data to pass them to the php file as a string, I don’t know how to pass my json data to it in sn alternative way with ajax

Comment: Yes, `$.ajax` post request takes an object as `data` argument, jQuery takes care of the proper formatting. In the JS, you should only set `let data = JSON.parse(<?= json_encode($data_array) ?>);`, and in the `$.ajax` arguments: `data: data`, that should be all you need. Notice, that you're passing an empty array to JSON.parse as the [replacer argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#parameters), which is expected to be a function.

Comment: Notice, that in PHP you've to `echo $data;`, the JSON string should not be re-encoded.

Comment: Thanks, I’ve done it and it works smoothly